# Custom malloc implementation

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-optimization, posix

I have a `malloc()` implementation that relies purely on `mmap`. I'm fairly sure that it doesn't overwrite any of the internal structures or have any other breaking issues, but I'm not totally sure about that.

Some details:

- `__PTRx__` (where `x` is `16`, `32`, or `64`) is defined when a pointer is `x` bits in size.
- I would appreciate any notes as to if this isn't ISO C or POSIX-compatible.
- I'm going for compiled code-size.
- Please, no notes on `goto`.

Here's the code:

allocation.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include "malloc.h"

int __get_next_allocation(size_t size)
{
    size_t ctr = 0;
    int found_allocation = 0;
    struct allocation_info *tmp_alloc = NULL;
    struct malloc_chunk *tmp_chnk = NULL;

    if(!__mallchunk)
        if(__get_next_chunk())
            return -1;

    if(!__allocinfo)
        __allocinfo = __mallchunk->start;

    tmp_alloc = __allocinfo;
    tmp_chnk = __mallchunk;

    while(tmp_chnk->prev != NULL)
        tmp_chnk = tmp_chnk->prev;

    for(ctr = 0;
        ctr < tmp_chnk->alloc_cnt && tmp_alloc;
        ctr++, tmp_alloc = tmp_alloc->next)
    {
        if( tmp_alloc->free &&
            tmp_alloc->size >= size )
        {
            found_allocation = 1;
            tmp_alloc->prev->next = tmp_alloc->next;
            tmp_alloc->next->prev = tmp_alloc->prev;
            tmp_alloc->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found_allocation)
    {
        if((size_t)(__allocinfo->start - __mallchunk->start)
                > ((CHUNK_SIZE - size) - sizeof(*tmp_alloc)))
        {
            if(__get_next_chunk())
                return -1;
            tmp_alloc = __mallchunk->start;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_alloc = __allocinfo->start +
                        __allocinfo->size;
        }

        tmp_alloc->start = (void *)tmp_alloc
                    + sizeof(*tmp_alloc);
        tmp_alloc->next = NULL;
    }
    __allocinfo->next = tmp_alloc;
    __allocinfo->next->prev = __allocinfo;
    __allocinfo = __allocinfo->next;
    __allocinfo->size = size;
    __allocinfo->free = 0;
    __mallchunk->alloc_cnt++;
    return 0;
}
```

calloc.c:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void *ret;

    if(size % 2) size++;
    if(nmemb % 2) nmemb++;

    size *= nmemb;
    ret = malloc(size);

    if(!ret) return NULL;
    return memset(ret, 0, size);
}
```

chunk.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include "malloc.h"

int __get_next_chunk(void)
{
    struct malloc_chunk *mallchunk = mmap(NULL,
                                    CHUNK_SIZE,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                                            -1,
                                            0);
    if(mallchunk == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!__mallchunk)
    {
        __mallchunk = mallchunk;
        __mallchunk->chunk_cnt = 0;
        __mallchunk->alloc_cnt = 0;
        __mallchunk->prev = NULL;
        __mallchunk->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        __mallchunk->chunk_cnt++;
        __mallchunk->next = mallchunk;
        __mallchunk->next->chunk_cnt =
                __mallchunk->chunk_cnt;
        __mallchunk->next->prev = __mallchunk;
        __mallchunk = __mallchunk->next;
        __mallchunk->alloc_cnt = 0;
        __mallchunk->next = NULL;
    }

    __mallchunk->start = (void *)__mallchunk +
                        sizeof(*__mallchunk);
    return 0;
}
```

free.c:

```
#include "malloc.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void free(void *ptr)
{
    struct allocation_info *tmp_allinfo = __allocinfo;

    if(!ptr) return;

    while(tmp_allinfo->prev)
        tmp_allinfo = tmp_allinfo->prev;

    while(tmp_allinfo && tmp_allinfo->start != ptr)
        tmp_allinfo = tmp_allinfo->next;

    if(!tmp_allinfo) return;

    memset(tmp_allinfo->start, 0, tmp_allinfo->size);
    tmp_allinfo->free = 1;
}
```

malloc.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "malloc.h"

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if(__get_next_allocation(size))
        return NULL;
    return __allocinfo->start;
}
```

malloc.h:

```
#ifndef _MALLOC_H
#define _MALLOC_H 1

#include <features.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef __PTR16__
# define CHUNK_SIZE (0x4000) /* 16K */
#else
# define CHUNK_SIZE (0x10000) /* 64K */
#endif

struct malloc_chunk
{
    void *start;
    size_t alloc_cnt;
    size_t chunk_cnt;
    struct malloc_chunk *prev;
    struct malloc_chunk *next;
};

struct allocation_info
{
    void *start;
    size_t size;
    int free;
    struct allocation_info *prev;
    struct allocation_info *next;
};

extern struct malloc_chunk *__mallchunk;
extern struct allocation_info *__allocinfo;

extern int __get_next_chunk(void);
extern int __get_next_allocation(size_t size);

#endif
```

metadata.c:

```
#include "malloc.h"

struct malloc_chunk *__mallchunk;
struct allocation_info *__allocinfo;
```

realloc.c:

```
#include "malloc.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LESSER(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (y) : (x))

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    size_t newsize = 0;
    void *newptr = malloc(size);

    struct allocation_info *tmp_allinfo = __allocinfo;

    if(!ptr) goto end;

    while(tmp_allinfo->prev)
        tmp_allinfo = tmp_allinfo->prev;

    while(tmp_allinfo && tmp_allinfo->start != ptr)
        tmp_allinfo = tmp_allinfo->next;

    if(!tmp_allinfo)
        return NULL;

    newsize = LESSER(tmp_allinfo->size, size);

    memcpy(newptr, ptr, newsize);

end:
    free(ptr);
    return newptr;
}
```

EDIT: If anybody wants to use this code, it's licensed under the LGPL: [link to repository](https://github.com/JL2210/minilibc.git)

Comment: What happens if you try to malloc 150K?  That's larger than your CHUNK size.  `realloc` will misbehave if the `malloc` call fails.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yeah, I'm working in fixing that; for now, I'll impose a hard limit. I just fixed a bug (used `strace`, great tool) that caused this to always allocate a new block of memory every time it was called. I'll keep this as is, though, to see if somebody else catches it (and comes up with a better solution).

Comment: No notes on `goto`?  Not even to say that it's perfectly appropriate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unnecessary code**

There is no need to make `size, nemb` even values.

```
if(size % 2) size++;
if(nmemb % 2) nmemb++;
```

**`__get_next_allocation(size_t size)` may benefit with rounding up of `size`**

Say you want allocations to be a multiple of 8.

```
#define ALLOC_MULTIPLE 8
int __get_next_allocation(size_t size) {
  if (size % ALLOC_MULTIPLE) {
    if (size > SIZE_MAX - ALLOC_MULTIPLE) {
      return -1;
    }
    size += ALLOC_MULTIPLE - (size % ALLOC_MULTIPLE); 
  }
  ...
```

**`calloc()` does not detect overflow**

```
if (nmemb > 0 && SIZE_MAX/nmemb > size) {
  return NULL;  // allocation too big.
} 
// Now safe to multiply.
size *= nmemb;
```

**Non compliant math**

In C, adding to a `void *` is UB.  May be OK in Posix.

```
// (void *)tmp_alloc + sizeof(*tmp_alloc);
(char *)tmp_alloc + sizeof(*tmp_alloc);
```

Note: `ENOMEM` is not ISO C.

**Non compliant alignment**

The value returned from `*alloc()` is expected to be aligned for all types.  By adding `sizeof(*__mallchunk)`, coding may lose this vital property - thus UB.  Various ways to handle this, yet code needs to insure `__mallchunk->start` has an aligned value.

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated §7.22.3 1.

Comment: In POSIX, it's also UB. Thanks for pointing that out.